# How to sum value if both rows are equal?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my Query

```
Select 
    AgentActivityLog.StatusDateTime, 
    AgentActivityLog.UserId, 
    AgentActivityLog.StateDuration /60 AS Minutes, 
    AgentActivityLog.StatusKey
FROM UserWorkgroups 
INNER JOIN AgentActivityLog ON UserWorkgroups.UserId = AgentActivityLog.UserId 
WHERE 
   AgentActivityLog.StatusDateTime Between '08/01/2013' AND '08/02/2013' AND 
   StatusKey IN ('Shadow Trainer') AND
    (UserWorkgroups.WorkGroup in ('LV_GR_9','LV_CCS_GENERAL','LV_PBX_INTERNAL'))
ORDER BY 
    AgentActivityLog.StatusDateTime, 
    AgentActivityLog.UserId, 
    AgentActivityLog.StatusKey, 
    AgentActivityLog.StateDuration
```

The Result

```
2013-08-01 08:59:03.000 JMENDOZA1   13  Shadow Trainer
2013-08-01 09:13:50.000 JMENDOZA1   12  Shadow Trainer
```

I want the result to sum the StateDuration for the day
something like this

```
2013-08-01 08:59:03.000 JMENDOZA1 25    Shadow Trainer.
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum both" ?

Comment: What column do you want to use to sum the values... What summed? What unique?

Comment: Use `sum` with `group by`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have eddited my original post.

Comment: After reading few more articles in this forum I finally got my query to work the way I want to.  I edited my original post to share with everyone. Thank you guys this is great place to learn SQL.

Comment: You should have left your original SQL and posted the solution as an answer. You can answer your own questions; in fact there is a badge for doing that. SO is also a repository for others to search for answers, and if you remove the original question it is less useful for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY UserId`, so rows with same user ID are grouped. In the rest of the columns of the `SELECT` list, aggregate functions have to be applied. You want `SUM()` for the `StateDuration` and probably `MIN()` or `MAX()` (or both!) for the `StatusDateTime`.

You can also use aliases to improve readibility:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(aal.StatusDateTime) AS MinStatusDateTime, 
    MAX(aal.StatusDateTime) AS MaxStatusDateTime, 
    aal.UserId, 
    SUM(aal.StateDuration / 60) AS Minutes, 
    'Shadow Trainer' AS StatusKey
FROM UserWorkgroups AS uw
  INNER JOIN AgentActivityLog AS aal ON uw.UserId = aal.UserId 
WHERE 
    aal.StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-02' AND 
    aal.StatusKey IN ('Shadow Trainer') AND
    uw.WorkGroup IN ('LV_GR_9','LV_CCS_GENERAL','LV_PBX_INTERNAL')
GROUP BY 
    aal.UserId
ORDER BY 
    MinStatusDateTime, 
    UserId, 
    StatusKey, 
    Minutes ;
```